# Grab Access token - ASP Net Cor 2.x webapp ( work or School Account )

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2b

I have created a simple Web application using Visual Studio 2017.
By selecting below template and after providing my domain details, VS created a project which is ready and protected by Azure AD.

[image]

Now, after logging in, I want to capture the Access token returned by the Azure AD Identity Server.  I want to examine that token in https://jwt.io/

Is there any way to plug in code in this framework to gram the access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Now, after logging in, I want to capture the Access token returned by the Azure AD Identity Server. I want to examine that token in https://jwt.io/

That seems you just want to check the `ID token` in jwt.io .ID token is sent to the client application as part of an OpenID Connect flow and is used by the client to authenticate the user. Please refer to document : [ID tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens) .

Access tokens enable clients to securely call APIs protected by Azure . Please refer to document : [Azure Active Directory access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens) .

For testing , one way to get the token is from one of the `OpenIdConnectEvents` :

```
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {

        OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
        {
            var Token = ctx.SecurityToken.RawData.ToString();

        },

    };
});
```

If you want to get the access token for accessing resource which protected by Azure AD , you should use [ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries)(Azure AD V1.0 endpoint) to obtain the token , see code sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Extensions/AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs#L66) . Or use [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet) if you are using Azure AD V2.0 endpoint .